# C# Sorting a DataTableCollection by a common column in each table

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I'm having some troubles figuring out how to sort a DataTableCollection.  The scenario is that each table in the collection would have the same schema and have a column called "JobNumber" which I want to sort on.  The data in these tables would need to be processed in that order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you need to sort data from all tables together or for each table separatly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTableCollection col;

  foreach(DataTable tbl in col)
  {
    // Get the DefaultViewManager of a DataTable and sort it.
    DataTable1.DefaultView.Sort = "JobNumber";
  }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well it's easy to iterate throught the tables in the collection, but as for sorting each one, you may want to see:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use SortedList fill it with rows from all DataTables, that's if your JobNumer is unique, something like that :

```
public SortedList<int, DataRow> SortDataTableCollection(DataTableCollection col)
{
  SortedList<int, DataRow> result = new SortedList<int, DataRow>();
  foreach(DataTable tbl in col)
  {
    foreach(DataRow rw in tbl.Rows)
    {
      result.Add((int)rw["JobNumber"], rw);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, adding items one-by-one to a SortedList is not an efficient way to sort things.